# Distinct IEqualityComparer<> problems

Tags: c#, linq

Hi all i'cant figure out why its not working need some help. I have a list with links and some data i want to distinct list by link host here the code

```
    public class DataContainerEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataContainer>
        {
            public bool Equals(DataContainer x, DataContainer y)
            {
                return x.Url.Host == y.Url.Host;
            }

            public int GetHashCode(DataContainer obj)
            {
                return obj.Url.GetHashCode();
            }
        }

List<DataContainer> items = new List<DataContainer>();
var item = new DataContainer("http://google.com/123");
items.Add(item);
item = new DataContainer("http://google.com/1234");
items.Add(item);
item = new DataContainer("http://google.com/12345");
items.Add(item);
item = new DataContainer("http://google.com/123456");
items.Add(item);
item = new DataContainer("http://google.com/1234567");
items.Add(item);                
items = items.Distinct(new DataContainerEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

after this nothing happens. Thx in advance.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Nothing happens"? What is supposed to happen?

Comment: I mean that i expect that in collection stay only one object. Daniel explain what wrong in my code thx all of you guys)))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem with your implementation of `DataContainerEqualityComparer` is that you are returning the hash code of the Url and not that of the Host.

Change it to this and it should work as expected:

```
public int GetHashCode(DataContainer obj)
{
    return obj.Url.Host.GetHashCode();
}
```

When checking two objects for equality the following happens:

First, `GetHashCode` is called on both objects. If the hash code is different, the objects are considered not equal and `Equals` is *never called*.
`Equals` is only called when `GetHashCode` returned the same value for both objects.